# Reference Class Member Triviality

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Let's say, for reasons of my own, I want a class to have a non-static reference member. I would think that this type should be easily optimized out of most code that uses it. Therefore, I assert its triviality in a unit test.

Clang and GCC agree that the class is trivial, but MSVC disagrees. Who is right, and why, according to the standard?

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct example {
    int& r;
};


// Clang and GCC let this pass
// MSVC fires this assertion
static_assert(
    std::is_trivial<example>::value,
    "example is not trivial"
);
```

Comment: I think that asking whether the class is "trivial" or not is the wrong question for your purposes (of wanting to ensure certain optimizations are possible), for technical reasons I explain in my answer. Also, you can have a class with 100 int members, and it would still be "trivial", even though it would be kinda expensive to copy.

Comment: Well, that's just the path from which I got to this language-lawyer question, I'm curious about the lawyer answer whether I ever write this again in my life or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to C++17 [class]/6, for a class to be trivial, among other requirements, it has to  have at least one non-deleted default constructor. The `example` class's default constructor is deleted, so `example` is not a trivial class.

Before C++17, the situation is somewhat less clear. It was required for a trivial class to have a trivial default constructor, and it was not clear whether a deleted default constructor qualifies as trivial. Richard Smith asked in [CWG 1928](http://wg21.link/cwg1928) whether special member functions that are defaulted and implicitly deleted are trivial. The Committee's response was:

> CWG feels that the triviality of a deleted function should be irrelevant. Any cases in which the triviality of a deleted function is observable should be amended to remove that dependency.

Subsequently, the resolution of [CWG 1496](http://wg21.link/cwg1496) resolved this issue in the case of trivial classes: it no longer matters whether a deleted default constructor qualifies as trivial, because in C++17, the definition says that *all* default constructors (in case there are multiple) must be *either trivial or deleted* and at least one must be non-deleted.

It seems that GCC and Clang may have been considering deleted default constructors as trivial, and haven't been updated with the C++17 definition of "trivial class". You should file bug reports.

Comment: GCC already has a bug report [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85723) and Clang [here](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41915).

Comment: How can there be multiple default constructors? Should I ask a new question about that instead of here in the comments?

Comment: @ZuodianHu Yes, please ask a new question.

Comment: Asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60877011/multiple-default-constructors