# Multiple Default Constructors

Tags: c++, overloading, language-lawyer, default-constructor, constructor-overloading

From [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60876410/reference-class-member-triviality/60876733?noredirect=1#comment107706222_60876733) the answer contains this quote:

> ... definition says that all default constructors (in case there are multiple) ...

How can there be multiple default constructors, and why may that be useful or allowed by the standard?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Default constructors don't have to have no parameters; they just need to be invocable with no arguments.

This condition is fulfilled by any constructor whose arguments all have defaults.

> [`[class.dtor/1]:`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.default.ctor#1) A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X for which each parameter that is not a function parameter pack has a default argument (including the case of a constructor with no parameters). *[..]*

```
struct Foo
{
   Foo(int a = 0);
   Foo(std::string str = "");
};
```

Now, of course, in this example you cannot actually instantiate a `Foo` using either of them without providing an argument (the call would be ambiguous). But `Foo` is still usable, and these are still "default constructors". That's just how the standard has decided to categorise things, for the purpose of defining rules. It doesn't really affect your code or programming.

<sup>(By the way, I didn't want to distract but you should have `explicit` on both of those!)</sup>

Comment: Can you expand on how overload resolution works this case?

Comment: @ZuodianHu Not very well ;)

Comment: Haha that's totally fair

Comment: The constructor could also be a variadic template using a function parameter pack I guess. In that case overload resolution could distinguish between them.

Comment: Also consider that this is such a poorly-designed class that there's no need for the committee to spend time optimising for it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of a class with two default constructors that can be default constructed:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(); // #1

    template <class... Args>
    Foo(Args...); // #2
};

auto test()
{
    Foo f{}; // ok calls #1
}
```

Comment: is it because the template functions are less preferable during overload resolution?