Why is having two default constructors only an error if you construct an object of that type?
Here's an example:
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                             
struct C {                                                                                                     
  C() { printf("hello!\n"); }                                                                                  
  C(bool a = false) { printf("hi!\n"); }                                                                       
};                                                                                                             
                                                                                                               
int main() {                                                                                                   
  //  C c;                                                                                                     
}   

If you uncomment the line in main, this is an error, but if you leave it commented, it is not.
My question is why it's not an error unless you do C c;. As in, it should be proactive and say error as soon as it sees something like this, since it is not usable.
In other words: what makes an invalid overload set, and why does the ambiguity of the no-arg constructor only make it invalid if an object is constructed with no arguments and not when the compiler recognizes the possibility?

You can't overload functions on just return type. But wait, constructors don't have return type! So no error there.

However, the same ambiguity results @user12002570 so why is it not a problem for the constructor case?

Both of your constructors are default constructors! How is the compiler supposed to know which one to use for C c; See this answer in the dupe: So can a class have two default constructors?

Exactly @user12002570 , so this should be a multi-definition error of some sort, but it's not an error unless you actually construct that object. This question is about that, not about the foo example I put out.

My question is why it's only an error when I do C c; -- I think it should be an error even without that.

See this answer that explains that C c; won't work but if you comment C c; the program will compile but as expected uncommenting C c; should/will give an ambiguity error.

You're not comparing apples to apples. Your two constructors differ in their parameters. To match that, your functions should have the same difference, as in int foo() { return 0; }
bool foo(bool a = false) { return a; } (which compiles without errors when they are not called).

Your two function overloads aren't ambiguous; they're an invalid overload set.  Try int foo() and int foo(bool a = false) and you'll see they behave exactly like the constructors.

My question is why @user12002570

Because the compiler has no way of knowing which one to use for C c;. See also Multiple Default Constructors

So then the question should be expanded to why invalid overload sets are only a problem if they are called, and not if they are defined @MilesBudnek

@user12002570 I will be clear. My question is why it's not an error unless you do C c;. As in, it should be proactive and say error as soon as it sees something like this, since it is not usable.

@user129393192 Because the c++ standard allows us to have multiple default ctors. Note that your program will compile if you write C c(true); 

@user129393192 The invalid overload set is a problem when not called.  C() and C(bool a = false) are a perfectly valid overload set however; C c{false}; clearly and unambiguously calls C(bool).  It's only a no-arg call that's ambiguous.

Exactly @MilesBudnek I'm curious why we do not error due to the no-arg call being ambiguous. It points to a potential error or mistake. In other words, there is no way to call the constructor that has no parameter variables.

@user129393192 "why it's not an error unless you do C c;..." Because the overload set itself is not invalid.  For instance you can still use C c(true); and the parameterized ctor will be used. Refer to the dupes.

Sadly "why was C++ designed the way it was?" is a question that only Bjarne Stroustrup can answer.

I think the question is valid and not answered by the proclaimed duplicates. None of the others mention the overload set that you both do. The question could essentially be reduced to : what makes an invalid overload set, and why does the ambiguity of the no-arg constructor only make it invalid if an object is constructed with no arguments?

"why does the ambiguity of the no-arg constructor only make it invalid if an object is constructed with no arguments?..." You're confusing the overload set begin invalid with the call C c; begin invalid. Only the call is invalid because as i said no way to know which ctor to use but that doesn't mean that the call C c; makes the overload set invalid.

I removed the questions about overloading on return type from the duplicate list, since that does not apply to this situation

@M.M Yeah, OP actually edited that part of their original question. If you see the original question you'll see/find that.

The linked duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60877011/multiple-default-constructors seems to explain the rationale for allowing multiple default constructors; and only generating an error when an attempt to use one is ambiguous

@user129393192 The important thing is that the 2nd ctor is also a parameterized ctor which is why the overload set itself is not invalid and also why C c(true); works.

"I think the question is valid..." I agree | "not answered by the proclaimed duplicates. ..." I disagree

The duplicates ask how is it possible to get multiple default constructors, and the answers describe situations like the one in this question, with some mentioning that there is no error unless you try to use default construction. I see this question taking things another step forward, asking why this situation exists. This is something not covered by those other questions, so I'm going to re-open this (and answer this, which might help demonstrate how this question is different than the others).

Does this answer your question? Multiple Default Constructors


As in, it should be proactive and say error as soon as it sees something like this, since it is not usable.

What you're seeing is an idiosyncrasy of constructors. In this respect, constructors are being treated the same as other functions, presumably because a simpler language specification (one with fewer special cases) is easier to get right.
So let's look at the same setup using regular functions. Instead of two constructors that can be called without arguments, here are two definitions of a function named foo() that can each be called without arguments. This is the same basic setup, where one definition takes no parameters, while the other has a default value for its lone parameter.
int foo() { return 22; }
bool foo(bool a = false) { return a; }

int main() {                                                                                                   
    return foo(); // ERROR!
} 

With this setup, you also get an error because of ambiguity. I hope we can agree that this is essentially the same situation, just without constructors.
Here's the interesting part: the first version of foo() can be invoked.  It takes an indirect approach, but it can be done. It is not fair to say that this setup is definitely an error.
When I say "indirect", I am alluding to indirection. The address of the first foo() can be taken (ambiguity resolved via a static_cast), then that pointer can be used to invoke the function.
int foo() { return 22; }
bool foo(bool a = false) { return a; }

int main() {                                                                                                   
    auto fptr = static_cast<int(*)()>(foo);
    return fptr(); // Programs compiles, runs, and exits with code 22.
} 

That should establish that this situation is not necessarily an error for regular functions. While the same cannot be said for constructors (one cannot take the address of a constructor), constructors are functions, and they share a lot of the characteristics of functions. Making a special case for this scenario either is not a priority or does not bring enough benefit to justify the complication.
(On the other hand, a compiler could offer a warning when multiple default constructors exist. Warnings are often issued for things that are legal by the language standard but probably are not what the programmer intended. Whether or not a compiler does so is up to the specific compiler.)
